# Can't sent few images in management_form, images are missing

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, formset

I have django app (django 1.6) and I have problem to send few images, to upload few images.
On front-end side this is OK, I can drag and drop images and see them there.

The problem starts when I push save button. From few images uploaded in front-end side, now I can see only one. So, for example, from 4 uploaded images in front-end, now I can see only one.

I don't know where can be a problem.
I'll be thankful for any help.

My url:

```
url('^post/create/$', PostAdd.as_view(), name="event_create"),
```

My views:

```
class PostAdd(BasePostEdit):
    permission_required = 'calendars.can_create_posts'
```

Paretnt view:

```
class BasePostEdit(PermissionRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "calendars/post_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_permission_object(self):
        return self.request.session["current_calendar"]

    def get_context_data(self, form):
        context = super(BasePostEdit, self).get_context_data()

        if form.instance.pk:
            # if we get an url to edit a post set the current calendar to posts
            # calendar
            self.request.session["current_calendar"] = form.instance.calendar
            # update seen by
            PostSeenBy.update_seen_by([form.instance, ], self.request.user)

        cur_calendar = self.request.session["current_calendar"]
        locales = []
        initial = {'calendar': cur_calendar}

        for loc in cur_calendar.locales.all():
            if not loc.pk in form.instance.locales.values_list("locale", flat=True):
                locales.append({'locale':loc})

        if not form.instance.pk:
            AllLocaleFormset = inlineformset_factory(Post, PostLocale, formset=BasePostLocaleFormset, extra=cur_calendar.locales.count())
            formset = AllLocaleFormset(initial=locales, instance=form.instance)
        else:
            PostLocaleFormset = inlineformset_factory(Post, PostLocale, formset=BasePostLocaleFormset, extra=len(locales))
            formset = PostLocaleFormset(queryset=form.instance.locales.all(), initial=locales, instance=form.instance)

        if self.request.GET.get('pub_date', None):
            date = datetime.strptime(self.request.GET.get('pub_date'), "%d/%m/%Y")
        elif form.instance.pub_date:
            import pytz
            date = form.instance.pub_date.astimezone(pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))
        else:
            # date = date.today()
            date = now().date()

        context['back_url'] = reverse_lazy('home_month', kwargs={
            'calendar': cur_calendar.slug,
            'year': date.year,
            'month': date.month})

        context['form'] = form
        context['post'] = form.instance
        context['current_calendar'] = self.request.session["current_calendar"]
        context['locales'] = formset
        return context
```

Here is part of my html and I think problems part is in line `{% get_upload_forms post locale.nested %}` below is code from get_upload_forms:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static calendars_tags guardian_tags %}

{% block body-tag-classes %}skinny-header{% endblock body-tag-classes %}

{% block content %}
{% get_obj_perms user for current_calendar as "perm_list" %}
<form action="{% if post.pk %}{% url 'event_edit' post.pk %}{% else %}{% url 'event_create' %}{% endif %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset {% if 'can_edit_posts' not in perm_list %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %}>
      <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="" />

        {{ locales.management_form }}
        {% for locale in locales.forms %}
          <p>Locale {{ locale.locale.value|locale_code }}</p>
          {{ locale.description }}
          {{ locale.calendar }}
          {{ locale.id }}
          {{ locale.locale }}
          {% get_upload_forms post locale.nested %}
        {% endfor %}

      {{ form.version }}
  </fieldset>
```

Code of get_upload_forms

```
@register.inclusion_tag('calendars/includes/upload_forms.html', takes_context=True)
def get_upload_forms(context, post, forms):
    perm_list = context.get('perm_list', None)
    return locals()
```

Here is html of upload_forms.html:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
<ul class="uploads">
{% for formset in forms%}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for a in formset %}
        {% if 'can_edit_posts' in perm_list or a.attachment.value %}
        <li class="{% if not a.attachment.value %}empty{% endif %}" data-form-name="{{ a.attachment.html_name }}">
            {{ a.id }}{{ a.post_locale }}
            <div class="preview">
              <div class="action">
                <span class="icon-hospital">Add Image</span>
              </div>
                <img src="{% thumbnail a.attachment.value 400x400 autocrop=False %}" alt="{{ a.attachment.value.name }}">
              <input class="upload-media" name="{{ a.attachment.html_name }}" type="file" value="{{ a.attachment.name }}" multiple>
              <input type="hidden" class="files-to-exclude">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
              <div class="filename">{{ a.attachment.value.name }}</div>
              <div class="filesize">{{ a.attachment.value.size }}</div>
              <ul class="btn-group">
                <li class="download">
                  <a class="button icon-download-alt" href="{{ a.attachment.value.url }}" target="_blank"></a>
                </li>
              {% if formset.can_delete and 'can_edit_posts' in perm_list %}
                <li class="delete">
                  {{ a.DELETE }}
                  <label for="{{a.DELETE.auto_id}}" class="button icon-trash"></label>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="previews"></div>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** here is code from firebug

```
<ul class="uploads">

    <input id="id_FILES_4950-TOTAL_FORMS" name="FILES_4950-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="3"><input id="id_FILES_4950-INITIAL_FORMS" name="FILES_4950-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2"><input id="id_FILES_4950-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="FILES_4950-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000">


        <li class="" data-form-name="FILES_4950-0-attachment">
            <input id="id_FILES_4950-0-id" name="FILES_4950-0-id" type="hidden" value="4485"><input id="id_FILES_4950-0-post_locale" name="FILES_4950-0-post_locale" type="hidden" value="4950">
            <div class="preview">
              <div class="action">
                <span class="icon-hospital">Add Image</span>
              </div>
                <img src="/media/localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_155.jpg.400x400_q85.jpg" alt="localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_155.jpg">
              <input class="upload-media" name="FILES_4950-0-attachment" type="file" value="attachment" multiple="">
              <input type="hidden" class="files-to-exclude">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
              <div class="filename">localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_155.jpg</div>
              <div class="filesize">60651</div>
              <ul class="btn-group">
                <li class="download">
                  <a class="button icon-download-alt" href="/media/localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_155.jpg" target="_blank"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="delete">
                  <input id="id_FILES_4950-0-DELETE" name="FILES_4950-0-DELETE" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="id_FILES_4950-0-DELETE" class="button icon-trash"></label>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="previews"></div>
        </li>



        <li class="" data-form-name="FILES_4950-1-attachment">
            <input id="id_FILES_4950-1-id" name="FILES_4950-1-id" type="hidden" value="4486"><input id="id_FILES_4950-1-post_locale" name="FILES_4950-1-post_locale" type="hidden" value="4950">
            <div class="preview">
              <div class="action">
                <span class="icon-hospital">Add Image</span>
              </div>
                <img src="/media/localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_156.jpg.400x400_q85.jpg" alt="localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_156.jpg">
              <input class="upload-media" name="FILES_4950-1-attachment" type="file" value="attachment" multiple="">
              <input type="hidden" class="files-to-exclude">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
              <div class="filename">localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_156.jpg</div>
              <div class="filesize">60651</div>
              <ul class="btn-group">
                <li class="download">
                  <a class="button icon-download-alt" href="/media/localefile/16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o_156.jpg" target="_blank"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="delete">
                  <input id="id_FILES_4950-1-DELETE" name="FILES_4950-1-DELETE" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="id_FILES_4950-1-DELETE" class="button icon-trash"></label>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="previews"></div>
        </li>



        <li class="empty" data-form-name="FILES_4950-2-attachment">
            <input id="id_FILES_4950-2-id" name="FILES_4950-2-id" type="hidden"><input id="id_FILES_4950-2-post_locale" name="FILES_4950-2-post_locale" type="hidden" value="4950">
            <div class="preview">
              <div class="action">
                <span class="icon-hospital">Add Image</span>
              </div>
                <img src="" alt="">
              <input class="upload-media" name="FILES_4950-2-attachment" type="file" value="attachment" multiple="">
              <input type="hidden" class="files-to-exclude">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
              <div class="filename"></div>
              <div class="filesize"></div>
              <ul class="btn-group">
                <li class="download">
                  <a class="button icon-download-alt" href="" target="_blank"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="delete">
                  <input id="id_FILES_4950-2-DELETE" name="FILES_4950-2-DELETE" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="id_FILES_4950-2-DELETE" class="button icon-trash"></label>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="previews"></div>
        </li>



</ul>
```

Comment: inspect element and show what are you getting inside the src tag

Comment: @Exprator please check my edit on bottom my answer.

Comment: try changing the value to url like a.attachment.url and check

Comment: @Exprator where I should change this url? in <img scr='#'> ?

Comment: Yup after the thumbnail a.thumbnail.value inside the img tag where you want to display your image. Just chnage that value to a.attachment.url

Comment: @Exprator Unfortunatly, nothing happend with this: `<img src="{{ a.attachment.url }}" alt="">`. Still one image, instead of few is upload.